# Evaluation as Bifunctor

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

Let $\mathscr{B}$ be a category and let $\mathscr{A}$ be a small category. I am trying to show that the evaluation map $\operatorname{eval}: \mathscr{A} \times Func(\mathscr{A}, \mathscr{B}) \rightarrow \mathscr{B} $ given by $(A, F) \rightarrow F(A)$ is a bifunctor.

I am confused about where the evaluation map sends morphisms. I know that to be a bifunctor I need to make sure that the images of the morphisms compose in the appropriate way, but I am not sure how to construct this mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An arrow $(A,F)\to (B,G)$ in $\mathscr{A} \times Func(\mathscr{A}, \mathscr{B})$ is given by an arrow $f:A\to B$ in $\mathscr{A}$ and a natural transformation $\lambda:F\Rightarrow G$. The evaluation map should then send this to an arrow $FA\to GB$; the best way to do this is to define $\operatorname{eval}(f,\lambda)$ as $\lambda_B\circ F(f)$ or equivalently $G(f)\circ \lambda_A$. Then you can check that this is indeed a bifunctor.